Отключить скролл экрана после ре рендера React native
Пишу интернет магазин на реакте с expo и столкнулся с проблемой скролла экрана после ре рендера, экранов несколько и они работают с одними данными и поэтому событие рендера всего экрана может запускаться из других активных экранов.
Компонент KeyboardAwareScrollView имеет несколько вложенных FlatList и после запуска ре рендера экран скроллится наверх. Как можно заставить либо запомнить положение KeyboardAwareScrollView и вернуть его после рендера либо отключить автоскролл совсем. Компонент выбран так как в хедере имеется строка поиска, а содержимое не вмещается в один экран. Пробовал extraDatа что также вызывает повторный ре рендер и автоскролл на топ.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android

Это не работает
